# What's this rabbit doing in the corner of the Windows 10 search bar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I just recently installed Windows Subsystem for Linux on my PC which is running Windows 10 22H2, and after rebooting notice this 'rabbit' in the corner of the search box.  Clicking it just brings up the search function, and I can't appear remove it.  Nor can I find any reference on the internet to it. What is its purpose?

[image]

Comment: Thomas O - it's topical. Today Sunday January 2023 is the start of the 2023 lunar new year, starting the 'year of the rabbit'.

Comment: That's 'Today Sunday January **22** 2023'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on it or the search bar, turn off Search Highlights and News and Interests.

That should remove it.

There have been different highlights over time

Comment: John, I have always admired your combination of expertise and proactive attitude!  However, this is yet another example where it should have been marked as a duplicate before it was answered.

Comment: The answer was provided before it was marked as a duplicate.

Comment: BTW, it has been a very long time since I have seen you here. Good to see you